# There should be universal LaTeX/MathJax guide for sites supporting it

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stackexchange-2.0, help-text

Currently, [stats](http://stats.stackexchange.com), [math](http://math.stackexchange.com), [cstheory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com) and [physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) have MathJax support which turns LaTeX code into equation.

At least on math, occasionally there are users that do not know this feature or don't know it's possible to use LaTeX (MathJax), resulting a badly formatted post.

I suggest that there should be a common "LaTeX/MathJax typesetting help" page for those sites that enabled MathJax support, like the ["Markdown editing help"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) that is present on all sites. Preferably, there should also be a line

- LaTeX equations $\sin^2 \theta$

in the "How to Format" on the right hand side.

#### See also: [The MathJax help link should point to a more specific guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246184/the-mathjax-help-link-should-point-to-the-tutorial-on-mathematics)

Comment: Wait. Geeks aren't *born* knowing LaTeX?

Comment: You mean a _MathJaX_ help.  MathJaX =/= LaTeX.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: well, MathJax ≈ LaTeX-surrounded-by-dollar-signs

Comment: @Kip: \*shakes head sadly at the ignorance of youth\*.  I \emph{guess} it depends on what \textbf{you} mean by \LaTeX\ really.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is basically completed, but I can't find a good help / demos page to link to for MathJaX.

There is this:

http://www.mathjax.org/demos/

but oddly it requires users to "view source" before showing them the markup required, which is ... annoying.

Per suggestion, I am now changing it to

http://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/

Comment: Maybe you can pop a question on meta.math.se and ask the good people there to write one? Not sure how much work it would take though.

Comment: @YiJiang: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559. (I'm putting it here instead of meta.math.SE as this is not just a math.SE feature.)

Comment: I found the Wikipedia formula-writing page very helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula

Comment: Jeff, this was added as a comment to the meta.math post, but I'll repeat it here so you're more likely to see it- the help box is almost perfect, but MathJax will render the `$\sin^2 \theta$` in it, so what the user actually sees is "MathJax equation sin² θ", which isn't correct. It has to be wrapped between `<code/>` tags or `<span class="tex2jax_ignore"/>` tags to avoid MathJax parsing it.

Comment: I just spent 15 minutes trying to figure out how to do a simple subscript. Sending me off to http://www.mathjax.org/demos/ frankly wasted my time as I vainly clicked around looking for help. Please don't provide that link any more as there's no obvious way to get any syntax help! I wrote the MathJax people directly and they suggested http://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/. Would you please consider changing your link on the question-asking page to point there instead? It will save your users much wasted time and frustration.

Comment: @emt sure I can change it to that, checking that change in now.

Comment: Thanks a lot. There may be better resources out there (in fact, the MathJax folks asked me to keep them posted if a better one is found) but for now that one is at least adequate and did have syntax help like I was expecting.

Answer (score 18):

Let's write our own help page for our use of MathJax. Here is a start. It is based on Stack Overflow's own [Markdown editing help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help), the FAQ for typing math [on math.SE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117) and [Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/faq#latex), and "Using LaTeX" on [ask NRICH](https://nrich.maths.org/discus/messages/24097/66497.html).

Characters in ***`bold italics`*** indicate highlighting.

---

## [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) turns LaTeX markup into beautiful formulae

This site supports typesetting mathematical formula with AMS-LaTeX markup, powered by the MathJax rendering engine.

### Entering math mode

Surround the TeX code with dollar signs to insert an inline equation

```
The integers $x,y,z$ form a Pythagorean triplet when $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$.
```

and use double dollar signs to insert an equation in its own line

```
The Bessel functions $J_n(x)$ and $Y_n(x)$ are
solutions to the Bessel equation
$$ x^2 y'' + x y' + (x^2 - n^2) y = 0 $$
where $n$ is a constant.
```

### Basic LaTeX markup

- Superscript and subscript — `x^2`, `a_n`, `a_{n+1}`, `H_n^{(2)}`
- Spacing — `a\ b` (text space). [Other kinds of spacing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula#Spacing).
- Square root and radicals — `\sqrt{x}`, `\sqrt[3]{x}`
- Fraction — `\frac{a}{b}`
- Sum and integral — `\sum_{k=0}^n k^2`, `\int_0^1 x^3 dx`
- Greek letters — `\alpha` (α) to `\omega` (ω); `\Gamma` (Γ) to `\Omega` (Ω)
- Symbols — `\ne` (≠), `\ge` (≥), `\le` (≤), `\sim` (∼), `\pm` (±), `\to` (→), `\infty` (∞), etc.
- Function names — `\sin`, `\cos`, `\log`, `\lim`, etc.

Visit [Detexify<sup>2</sup>](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) to lookup command for a symbol.

Check [the MathJax documentation](http://www.mathjax.org/resources/docs/?tex.html#supported-latex-commands) for the complete list of commands supported.

### Show source

Right-clicking on any equations should reveal a context menu. Clicking "Show source" will open up a new window showing the LaTeX markup that generates it.

### Need More Detail?

[The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2e](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf) is a good beginner's guide on the LaTeX system.

Comment: Let's get this up! Right now the link provided is not helping anybody.

Comment: Lack of proper docs & examples is actually getting worse, as even more fantasy-themed sites such as [Worldbuilding](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/editing-help) are supporting it, but only link to _mathjax.org_, which only links to _docs.mathjax.org_ which has LaTeX links to the glossary of _docs.mathjax.org_ which links to _wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX_... 15 clicks and 3 deliberate searches later to find something that resembles respectable docs just to type `$\Delta$`. This may be the opportunity for [SO Docs](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation) to step up as the de-facto resource.

Answer (score 12):

I [brought this up on meta.math](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1159/show-latex-syntax-in-how-to-format-box) and was directed to this question. I thought I'd share the mockup here too, showing what I'd like:

[image]

Comment: Heyo, and guess what happened! At least on math.SE

Answer (score 6):

A **much much** more detailed MathJax tutorial/reference has been created on Math.SE: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)