# Where can I find a guide to create formulae or equations?

Tags: support, mathjax

If I ask a question and need to use equations and formulae, where can I find a guide to create symbols for formula writing, useful for maths, physics, or engineering, etc.?

Comment: I assume you mean something like this: [There should be universal LaTeX/MathJax guide for sites supporting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it)

Comment: and this: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 4):

On sites that have MathJax enabled, the editing help has a short section [about LaTex](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

The help also links to the [MathJax site](http://www.mathjax.org/), where more information is available.

Comment: We know that Matjax == equations, but how do new users know that? There isn't a hint or something like that.

Comment: The "ask question" page has some hints: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArWs6.png

Comment: I see that, but how do I know that is about making nice formatted equations? I am not sure how common MathJax is in that world.

Comment: @PatrickHofman A heading saying `Mathjax Equations` provides a decent hint that it's tool for making equations. It's followed by link to "Mathjax Help" if someone's looking for such a tool and wanted to know more.